# iOS Application is crashing After updating to new version and new firebasedb

Tags: ios, firebase

happy to  see you again.
I was successfully submit and update application in appstore.

1. here iam facing one issue while updating app from app store app is getting crash(after launch Screen).
2. while on fresh installation application is working good.
3. no crash while testing and in TestFlight.
4. no crash reports available from store.
5. here I am using firebase db.

finally it's important to inform you.
my db is different from previous version(fbdb_1) to present version(fbdb_2).
whole data is same for two db's.

Any suggestion would be helpful in my learning journey

Comment: Add more details, crash log etc

Comment: Unable to produce crashlogs as it's happeneing today only.

Comment: What changed in the db? Is it user based database or independent?

Comment: Nothing changed, whole db is same.

Answer (score 0):

Checking for unsaved keys in home screen, due to this app is crashing.
Updated keys and now working fine without crash.